# "Easy to work with" in a Résumé

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to find a more succinct way of saying the phrase, "easy to work with".  "Easy going" just sounds too lazy.

---

Added from comments:

"Team player" is cliché, however "flexible" is nice. I am in broadcasting, so it is a "hurry up and wait" kind of life. Or they may say, "I want it now, in a little while". One must stay positive when you rush to do something, and still have other things to take care of. Hence, "easy to work with" means you must keep cool and watch your mouth!

Comment: I would ask you here to be a bit more explicit, and describe what, in your mind, the phrase ***easy to work with*** means.

Comment: Not a negative prima donna

Comment: For use in a résumé, I believe you are groping toward the concept normally expressed with terms such as ***flexible*** and ***team player***. Again, it would be better to be more explicit in your description.

Comment: Team player is cliché, however flexible is nice.  I am in broadcasting, so it is a "hurry up and wait" kind of life.  Or they may say, "I want it now, in a little while".  One must stay positive when you rush to do something, and still have other things to take care of.  Hence, "easy to work with" means you must keep cool and watch your mouth!

Comment: Hi, Pam, welcome to EL&U. I added the text of your comment to the question; feel free to edit that or add more details (you can use the "edit" link to the bottom left of the question). The more detail you provide, the better the answers you will get. You also should provide the sentence from your résumé where you want to use the word—if it's, say, a list of bullets, then how you *would* use the word in a sentence if describing yourself in an interview. That will really help answerers get the right tone (and is technically required for single-word-requests).

Comment: Thank you.  It would be a bullet point.  And "multi tasking" is so over used.  I have described myself in speech many times as "flexible" and "easy", but easy can have too many connotations. So for the time being, Flexible is the word, until something better comes along!  Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Flexible*** definitely fits here, and (cliché or not) so does ***team player***. ***Eager to please*** might also fit, though it can carry connotations that may not be entirely appropriate; ***people-pleaser*** might be marginally better.

Your "problem", at base, is that the phrase ***easy to work with*** is ultimately very nebulous, and context-dependent. Instead of focussing on how to express this phrase, look at how to express the various aspects of *being easy to work with*, and express those in ways that are appropriate to the environment to which you are submitting the résumé.

Answer (score 1):

## Cool-headed

Not easily worried or excited.

## Temperate

Showing moderation or self-restraint.

## Cooperative

Involving mutual assistance in working toward a common goal.
Willing to be of assistance.

Comment: Hi, TheObliviousMe. You offer some good words, but your answer would be improved by citing your source for these definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use 'personable'. 'Easy going' might give the impression that you wouldn't work very hard.